# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory using os.unlink in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

The idea of the script is for the user to input a folder as a command line argument and have the code identify the extensions to remove. It works perfectly when I do a test run and just print the files and folders that will be removed, however when I run the script without the os.unlink parts uncommented, I get the FileNotFoundError...

```
#! usr/bin/python3

import os
import sys


def clean(path):
    extensions = (".txt", ".jpg", ".jpeg", ".nfo", ".png", ".bmp")

    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith(extensions):
                os.unlink(file)
                # print('Removing File:', os.path.join(root, file))

    for directories, names, files in os.walk(path):
        if os.listdir(directories):
            os.unlink(directories)
            # print('Removing Directory:', directories)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    filthy = sys.argv[1]
    clean(filthy)
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/a5pire/source/repos/plex/mediaClean/mediaClean.py", line 24, in <module>
    clean(filthy)
  File "/home/a5pire/source/repos/plex/mediaClean/mediaClean.py", line 13, in clean
    os.unlink(file)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'stuff.txt'
```

The stuff.txt file definitely exists.

Answer (score 0):

The `files` list as generated by `os.walk` contains just the file names. You should join the path names stored in `root` with the file names so that you have the full path names to pass to `os.unlink`:

```
os.unlink(os.path.join(root, file))
```

Also, if you intend to remove empty directories, you should do `if not os.listdir(directories):` rather than `if os.listdir(directories):`, but since you're already using `os.walk`, which returns the lists of subdirectories as the second item in the tuples generated, you should simply use it instead, and use the `topdown=False` parameter to ensure subdirectories get deleted before their parents:

```
for directories, names, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):
    if not names:
        os.rmdir(directories)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. That seems to have worked for the files, however now I get an error about the folders:

IsADirectoryError: [Errno 21] Is a directory: '/home/a5pire/source/repos/plex/mediaClean/testFiles/'

Comment: You should use `os.rmdir`, rather than `os.unlink`, to remove a directory.

Comment: This is actually getting somewhat frustrating. I am now getting the error telling me that the directories are not empty.... Obviously they arent because they contain other directories, so how do I get around this?

Comment: You've got your condition opposite. I've also updated my answer with an example of a better approach.